# Valid for Ruby class to extend itself but under a module?

Tags: ruby

Is it valid syntax to have a Ruby class extend itself, but under a separate module? For instance, I have an `ErrorsController` class..

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
 ....
end
```

But I want to have a different behavior if under a module..

```
class Share::ErrorsController < ErrorsController
 ....
end
```

Here ErrorsController is extending ErrorsController, which works fine. But then I wrote it in long form:

```
module Share
  class ErrorsController < ErrorsController
  end
end
```

There seemed to be problems sometime..

Comment: What do you mean by "there **seemed** to be problems"? Are there, or are there not problems? And what do you mean by "**sometime**"? At *what* times do there *seem* to be problems?

Comment: And what do you mean by a "class extend itself"? That is not possible in Ruby. A class can only extend an existing class, the inheritance clause is given in the class definition, at which point the class doesn't exist yet, ergo it cannot extend itself.

Comment: And BTW if you want to know if something is valid syntax, that is very easy to find out yourself: Just type it in and see if you get a `SyntaxError`. Alternatively, you can use `ruby -c` (**c**heck syntax).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To unambiguously refer to the "top-level" ErrorsController, the typical technique is to add two colons before it. So for example:

```
module Share
  class ErrorsController < ::ErrorsController
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If parent **ErrorsController** is stored in other module, you should use full path to it.
For example:

```
module Share
  class ErrorsController < OtherModule::ErrorsController
  end
end
```